# Error setting expression

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, type-conversion, el

For some reason I am getting the following error message:

```
Developer Notification (set struts.devMode to false to disable this message): Unexpected Exception caught setting 'claimForm.payableEvents[1].totalHours' on 'class com.somedomain.application.action.claimreimbursement.ProcessSaveClaimFormAction: Error setting expression 'claimForm.payableEvents[1].totalHours' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@54f242c1'
Developer Notification (set struts.devMode to false to disable this message): Unexpected Exception caught setting 'claimForm.payableEvents[2].totalHours' on 'class com.somedomain.application.action.claimreimbursement.ProcessSaveClaimFormAction: Error setting expression 'claimForm.payableEvents[2].totalHours' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@1ff32b5d' 
Developer Notification (set struts.devMode to false to disable this message): Unexpected Exception caught setting 'claimForm.payableEvents[1].totalHours' on 'class com.somedomain.application.action.claimreimbursement.ProcessSaveClaimFormAction: Error setting expression 'claimForm.payableEvents[1].totalHours' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@54f242c1'
Developer Notification (set struts.devMode to false to disable this message): Unexpected Exception caught setting 'claimForm.payableEvents[2].totalHours' on 'class com.somedomain.application.action.claimreimbursement.ProcessSaveClaimFormAction: Error setting expression 'claimForm.payableEvents[2].totalHours' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@1ff32b5d'
```

According to the article on [Parameters Interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/docs/parameters-interceptor.html) under the heading of Warning on missing parameters, it was my understanding that there was a problem with the setter on the parameter.

I have gone back and checked, I do indeed have a setter named properly for the parameter.

The following is a stripped down version of my java classes:

```
public class ClaimWizardPayableEventAjaxAction{
    private ClaimForm claimForm;

    public void setClaimForm(ClaimForm claimForm) {
      this.claimForm = claimForm;
    }
}


public class ClaimForm{
  private List<PayableEvent> payableEvents;

  public void setPayableEvents(List<PayableEvent> payableEvents) {
    this.payableEvents = payableEvents;
  }
}

public class PayableEvent{
  private BigDecimal totalHours;

  public void setTotalHours(BigDecimal totalHours) {
    this.totalHours = totalHours;
  }
}
```

With my jsp using a c:forEach:

`<input type="text" class="input-small" name="claimForm.payableEvents[${i.index}].totalHours" />`

As far as what what I have tried?   I have looked over my spelling and don't see any inconsistencies.  I have checked and it is indeed saving the value.  Does this have something to do with it being cast to a big `BigDecimal`?

Comment: Do you have getters as well?

Comment: Yes I do have the getters.  Just cleaned them out of the example.  All other properties set and without problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to the type conversion, because you are not using Struts tag the value is converted to string and back to the `BigInteger`. You might turn off `struts.devMode` if you don't like to get such warnings.

Comment: Well the warnings are good :-)   We are indeed still in dev.   Its just that we had not been seeing such warnings until recently. (One of the dev's upgraded the library we are using).  I was trying to confirm that nothing BAD was going on.

Comment: Nothing is bad indeed but something is not good, that's why these warnings. You may try to change the code to remove such warnings at the begining of using Struts. For adhoc development to save time devMode should be off.